# How to get Richtext Box in Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet

I need to display RichTextbox in my Applet window. If anybody know answer help me...

Im waiting for Ur answers.

Comment: Now that is a good question, I have no answer, but I can't remember when last I actually did Applets, thought everyone was on the Web 2.0 bus already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JEditorPane` which provides some basic RTF support.

All the information you might need can be found on Sun's tutorial at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html). Here is [howto](http://www.coderanch.com/t/346184/GUI/java/Rich-Text-Box-Java)